# Extra column being inserted at last in each table row in tbody

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am taking up data from a table in xampp database. I am getting all data printed in 2 columns, but somehow, I am getting an extra <td></td> inserted at last in all rows in tbody. Can someone tell me how and where is the problem?

PHP CODE:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."<td></tr>";}
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML output? And what is your desired output?

Comment: HTML output is 2 columns of Name and Email. Getting table with these 2 columns + a blank column at end in each row.

Comment: you have `<td>` instead of `</td>` in the end of 4th line

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the HTML you see and the HTML you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a closer look at `<td>".$row["email"]."<td></tr>` you didn't close the `td`

Make it as follows:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
....
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td></tr>";}
echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this while line:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."<td></tr>";}
```

To this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td></tr>";}
```

You accidentally put `<td>` where you meant to close it with this `</td>`

Comment: For all I know you could be a complete beginner and you wouldn't know what that meant. This way I can be sure anyone reading will understand :)